# List<t> does not get ordered properly with OrderBy

Tags: c#, sorting

My model has this structure:

```
public class resultadoDialogModel
{
    public int tipo        { get; set; }
    public int idDocIndice { get; set; }
    public int docIds      { get; set; }
}
```

And I  have a `List<resultadoDialogModel> newModel` with these values:

```
143 77 45 
142 75 44  
145 75 44
146 75 44
147 75 44
142 75 45
```

The middle column refers to `public int idDocIndice`

Now, when I sort the items in an ascending order this does not gets ordered properly

`var newModelOrdered = newModel.OrderBy(o => o.idDocIndice);`

```
142 75 44  
145 75 44
146 75 44
147 75 44
143 77 45 
142 75 45
```

The last 2 items are not ok. Why might this be happening?

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. By the looks of it, your data actually corresponds to `idDocIndice` being the *final* column in your output...

Comment: There is no `public int indices` in the class you show.

Comment: You are sure that idDocIndice isn't the third column in your list? It seems to be sorting on the 3rd column, not the second.

Comment: Are you calling `ToList` or `ToArray` on it in the end? Just confirming..

Comment: @JonSkeet Fixed the post Eren Thanks and you where right Jon. I have not notice that. I am not sure if there is a answer to this mistake but if you find a way, awnser the question and I´ll vote for that. Thanks a lot

Comment: It seems only the last item is not OK. Actually it seems you ordered by the last column, which is `docIds` (I have no idea actually without headings).

Comment: What's the code you're using to display these results?  Are you sure that `idDocIndice` isn't the last column? That one is sorted just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem's that an error occured like you ordered by docIds or your fill data  isn't correct

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that the property used for ordering was wrong.

This is the right way:

```
var newModelOrdered = newModel.OrderBy(o => o.tipo);
```

OrderBy was working properly on the wrong property